# How to construct Wiener Filter from powerspectrum?

Tags: time-series, data, data-cleaning, fourier

I am trying to construct a Wiener Filter, to filter the ratio of the peak from the cross-correlation function, between a galaxy spectra and a template spectra, with the peak of the auto-correlation function of the template. Therefor, I calculated the powerspectrum P(k) of the cross-correlation peak in Fourier-Space and normalized it (by deviding through its maximum):
$P(k)=|X_{Peak}(k)|^2$. This powerspectrum decomposes into a noise part and a signal part which become clearly visible in the logarithmic space. The following plot shows $\ln{P(k)}$:
[image]

In eq. (32) of Brault & White (1971) (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1971A%26A....13..169B/abstract) the Wiener Filter is described as: $W(k) = \frac{P'_S(k)}{P'_S(k)+P'_N(k)}$, where $P'_S(k)$ is a simple model for the signal part and $P'_N(k)$ a simple model for the noise part. I chose a parabola for the signal (central) part and linear functions (left and right tails) for the noise. With the following result:

[image]

Since I work with numeric arrays I am not sure how to actually apply eq. (32) for the Wiener Filter, since $P'_S$ is of course a shorter array than $P'_S(k)+P'_N(k)$, so the numerical division fails. Does anyone have an idea how to apply this filter equation to this case? After constructing the Wiener-Filter in the logarithmic space, I wanted to transfer it back using $\exp{W(k)}$.